# Arduino MKR Zero keyboard emulation not working

Tags: arduino, arduino-ide, arduino-c++

I bought a new Arduino MKR Zero which is generally promoted for playing sound from SD Card (SD card slot built-in on the board) but since the Microcontroller is `SAMD21`, I believe it supports keyboard emulation.

I am trying to simulate opening a file `code.txt` from SD card with the following code:

```
CTRL ESC
delay(100)
STRING r
delay(100)
STRING notepad
ENTER
```

and on the Arduino MKR Zero, I flashed the following code:

```
#include <SD.h>
#include <Keyboard.h>

File codeFile;
File logFile;

void setup() {

  pinMode(LED_BUILTIN, OUTPUT);
  Serial.begin(9600);
  delay(2000); // Allow time for the serial monitor to open

  Keyboard.begin();
  // Initialize the SD card
  if (!SD.begin()) { // Change the pin number according to your setup
    Serial.println("SD initialization failed!");
    return;
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("SD Initialized success!");
  }
  
  // Open the code file
  codeFile = SD.open("code.txt");
  if (!codeFile) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open code.txt");
    return;
  }
  else{
    Serial.println("code.txt found in SD Card.");
  }

  // Open the log file
  logFile = SD.open("log.txt", FILE_WRITE); // Open for writing (create if it doesn't exist)
  if (!logFile) {
    Serial.println("Failed to open log.txt");
    return;
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("log.txt opened in SD card.");
  }
  
  // Wait for the computer to recognize the USB connection
  delay(5000);

  // Execute the code from the file
  while (codeFile.available()) {
    char c = codeFile.read();
    Keyboard.write(c); // Send each character from the file as a keystroke
    logFile.write(c); // Write the character to the log file
    Serial.print(c); //print the character in Serial Monitor
    delay(20); // Adjust this delay as needed
  }
  
  // Close the files
  codeFile.close();
  logFile.close();

  Keyboard.end();
  Serial.println("\n\nEnd of code.");
  digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, HIGH);

}

void loop() {
  // Nothing to do here
}
```

The code uploads successfully on the board. Now, when I reset the board, I am getting the following output in the **Serial Monitor**.

```
SD Initialized success!
code.txt found in SD Card.
log.txt opened in SD card.
CTRL ESC
delay(100)
STRING r
delay(100)
STRING notepad
ENTER

End of code.
```

But this code is not doing anything on the Desktop. What am I doing incorrect here?

Comment: I don't see `Keyboard.begin()` in your setup()

Comment: @Juraj Just now tried adding ```Keyboard.begin()```, no luck still, updating the above code with ```Keyboard.begin()``` for everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, seems like it was driver issue.

I went to Device Manager and saw 2 drivers,
`Arduino MKR Zero (COM14)` with Code 10
`USB Serial Device (COM13)`

I uninstalled both the drivers, reboot and now, HID was working fine.
One issue, the HID was simply typing the contents of the `code.txt` file rather than executing it (I saw it typing `GUI r...` in notepad in Windows).

I just have to figure out how to execute it instead.